# Cannot install reportlab in pycharm(venv) on macOS

Tags: python, macos, reportlab

## The problem

- Right now I am trying to set up a virtual development environment on a macOS in pycharm.
- The issue that I am facing is with this command
  `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- I am using python 2.7 right now and I am needing to install reportlab==2.4
- I also get an error message when I try to install reportlab outside of pycharm and outside of my venv, that is if I explicitly do
  `pip install reportlab==2.4` in the terminal

I will include some of the screenshots of the errors but it is about 800+ lines of output going through the process of copying, creating, and displaying syntax error messages/other errors.

Something else that I have noticed is that a lot of the errors start with 'cc' which might be an issue because I am writing in pycharm on a mac and there might be some dependencies that I am missing/I don't have support for C code somewhere? I have installed xcode command tools already but the version of gcc might be too new/too strict? the version is `xcode-select version 2384`

I have tried a lot of things to get this working but cannot seem to crack it.
I will try to answer questions as I see them but in the meantime, if you have any suggestions, I am open to anything.

Thanks!

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

[image: error 3]

[image: error 4]

[image: error 5]

[image: error 6]

[image: error 7]

Comment: please copy-paste the error message as text rather than picture

Comment: The only problem with that is the error message is over 800 lines of output. I figured that the pictures would do a good job of highlighting some of the important pieces found in the errors. I can try to piece some of the text together though if that is easier to mess around with.

Comment: These screenshots show some warnings, but it's the errors what stop the thing working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** UPDATE **
I did see that most of these were just warnings.
I managed to find a command that suppressed these warnings and allowed reportlab==2.4 to install correctly.

`CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" pip install reportlab==2.4`

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thanks for the follow-up.